# Почему не работает spl_autoload_register в PHP?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Ничего не понимаю, перешерстил документацию вдоль и ничего.

Файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```js
set_include_path('W:/domains/conf/public_html/');

$dir = get_include_path() . 'classes/' . 'c1' . '.php';

//include $dir; Здесь всё подключается

function load1($class) {
    include get_include_path() . 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('load1'); // не подключается

new User();
```

Answer (score 0):

Имя класса в файле должно совпадать с именем файла